# Is there some software to design Android UI faster/better?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm an android developer.

Since the first day into the android studio, I started complaining about *my* abilities in graphic design for activities **UI** and now I'm looking for a **guide** or a **tutorial** that could help me with this. Kind of **newbie** help.

I already made my best out of the **simple** drawable, but I want to do **more**, I need some way to make vectors, to understand how to make (i.e.) new **button styles**. Just a few minutes ago I **gave up** on trying to make a simple shape that would have been placed as part of the background.

I tried finding something with google obviously but using words like *"design"* *"android studio"* *"vector"* and others always makes show up **irrelevant** results.

I have **no problem** looking for Java problems, but with a graphic, I'm complete **newbie**, and I'm frustrated even more because I can't find a way out of this ignorance.

** Thank you all** for your help!

Comment: as per your situation I would advice you get a graphics artist who would provide you with UI mock-ups(probably in photoshop/coreldraw) for your app and then export images for you to use as drawables or you could try tutorials on how to create different types of drawables in android(so you can use the mock ups as your blueprints)or if you aren't so new to android studio you could try adding UI libraries from [github](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui) to your app as per your requirement

Comment: for vector drawables https://stackoverflow.com/a/56019133/10138416

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Adobe XD for the fact that it is fairly easy and pretty straightforward to use and has some very helpful plugins that automate your task. I have zero knowledge of how to make vector or use those path and all things, but XD has some great tools which help me make any sort of background vector/shape or a custom shape for a particular preferences and it provides you with the means to export the designed graphics at the various dpi level that android needs, thus cutting down the problem of responsiveness and having to recreate the designs at different dpi levels or you could just export them as svg's and just forget about it.

[ADOBE XD!](https://www.adobe.com/products/xd.html?sdid=12B9F15S&mv=Search&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIuaGIyNXi5wIVxSMrCh099wZ9EAAYASAAEgIvIvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!3085!3!394015010050!e!!g!!adobe%20xd)

A great and free alternative would be FIGMA, not only it gives you all these but also the code to implement these yourself, it provides code for CSS, iOS and ANDROID.
Figma can be used on their site or you could download the desktop version.

[FIGMA](https://www.figma.com/design/)

Comment: There's no need to make random words bold. No, it doesn't require extra attention

Comment: Sure whatever you say Bud.